# React js - Using Bootstrap4 CDN, How to manually enable javascript event handlers in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have been going around the internet for a while with no hope at all.

I am using "collapse" bootstrap for toggling visibility of a div.

I need to control this toggling through react onClick. Bootstrap says can be accessed through "$('.collapse').collapse()" but for some reason i canot do this in react.....any suggestions other than importing jQuery or using react-bootstrap component ??

```
class Container extends Component {
  render() {
   return (

     <div className="wrapper">

          <div className="collapse in" id="collapseExample">
           <h1>Hide me</h1>
          </div>

          <div className="container">
           <div className="row">
             <button
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#collapseExample"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="collapseExample">
              Get a random Book
            </button>
          </div>
         </div>

    </div>
```

)
}

Comment: Yes, bootstrap requires jquery for the work of the collapse. Had the same issue, some time ago. Had to manually write js for the work of the collapse, tho it didn’t work by sliding (just opened and closed). If the solution using js is good for you, can try to find it, just let know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap javascript depends on jQuery. jQuery and React have different ways to manipulate the DOM. To avoid issues in the future, you shouldn't use both. If you are using React, [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is important.

A good React wrapper of Bootstrap is [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap). I recommend you use the library to build Bootstrap-based component, not write the Bootstrap raw class. A component named `Collapse` might fit your need, as you can see in sample code [here](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/).

If you are not interested in importing any library at all, it's fairly simple to write the component by yourself, using `state`. The internal idea is similar to the `Collapse` sample code above:

```
class MyCollapse extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };

  toggleState = () => this.setState( prevState => ({ isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleState}>Click to toggle</button>
        {
          this.state.isOpen &&
          <div className="my-collapse">
            {/* COLLAPSE CONTENT */}
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  };
}
```

Every time you click the button, the state attribute `isOpen` is toggled, which leads to a re-render of the component. That's one of the biggest strength of React: very flexible.

Comment: How about the expand and collapse animation?

Comment: Thanks. will take a look

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet illustrates how it should be done. If its still not working correctly in your program i would verify the CDN script links are correct.

Reminder, in ReactJS we should never use jQuery we manipulate the virtual DOM instead via components.

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => (
  <div>{props.label}</div>
);

// Example class component
class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (

       <div className="wrapper">

            <div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">
             <h1 className="card card-body">Hide me</h1>
            </div>

            <div className="container">
             <div className="row">
               <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Get a random book</button>
            </div>
           </div>

      </div>
  ) }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Container/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```